# Excel - Leading Space (??) visible in Cell but NOT in Formula Bar

Tags: vba, excel

In a cell the string "Usha" appears with what looks like a leading space, but in the Formula bar it appears correctly. Also, using LEFT(A1,1) returns "U" and not any other character. What is the cause of this behavior and what are the possible solutions (both UI and VBA)?

Comment: I presume you have tried the trim function? I wonder if the U a special character? You could check this in vba by looping through the chr function and then seeing what number chr the U is, but looks like we would need more information. Can you screenshot the contents of the cell?

Comment: U is not a special character. The length of the string "USHA" with and without TRIM is 4.  CODE(A2) where the string is located returns 85

Comment: This sounds like a cell formatting issue. Have you checked all of the alignment settings?

Answer (score 2):

Check the **indent** of that cell.

[image]

Use the left of the red marked buttons to remove the indent.

Comment: Clicking on the left indent button does not change the appearance of the string. Right click moves it further to the right.

Comment: @user1955215 can you add a screenshot into your original question? If you enter some new text into that cell does it look like having spaces too?

Comment: what do you use to get that torn paper effect?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Can't tell you, sorry. I used a screenshot that was previously posted on the Stack to not need to post one of my german Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Check the format of the cell.   I pasted text into a cell formatted as "Accounting" and observed the leading space in the cell (e.g. ' ABC') but not the formula bar.  Changed the cell format to Text and the space disappeared.